# Angular 6 I have 2 navbars and differents routes, but i have to put one or other in the same page

Tags: angular, data-binding

I have 2 navbars that I need to set, the first is the primary navbar and the second is for a section of the project but I need to maintain the second navbar  when you click a link in the footer.

The two links are the same but one is for general footer and the other is for help footer, How can I know if the click is from general or help footer? and how to show one or other navbar depends on that.

```
    <li><a routerLink="/sobre-nosotros">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
```

Comment: Hola Karen! are you putting the different footers in different components or it's in the same component?

Answer (score 0):

So If I understand you correctly, you have two bars, one of them always shows up and there is another nav bar which shows up only when you click a link in the footer right?
May be you can create an observable in helfooter component, when you detect the click in your helfooter component, emit values and subscribe to this observable in your second navbar component would help?

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Comment: I cannot comment because I don't have the required reputation, sorry! But I thought this can help her, so posted it here